# What's the endianness of iOS wchar_t?

Tags: ios, string, cocoa, unicode, character-encoding

Im my iOS 5.1 application, I use a 3rd party library which uses `wchar_t` for strings. This works fine internally, but I sometimes need to create an `NSString` for such string. I can use the following API:

```
- (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

But what encoding am I supposed to use? Since `wchar_t` in iOS is 32 bits, the candidate encodings are:

```
NSUTF32StringEncoding
NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding
NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding
```

Which byte order am I supposed to use? Should I use the encoding byte order corresponding to the result of `long NSHostByteOrder()`?

And by the way, which byte order is `NSUTF32StringEncoding` representing? Is it going to examine the bytes and deduce the byte order? And what will it yield when converting *from* NSString with `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:`?

Note that I am not concerned with data exchange between platforms here (though I may have to face that issue too someday).

Googling around didn't help much.

My hunch is that this is compiler-defined, e.g. what encoding is used by my compiler (CLang) when I write:

```
wchar_t *s = L"string with non ascii unicode characters such as éèüçß";
```

Of course it's easy enough to write a small sample program and find out, but I'd like a solution that doesn't rely on the specific implementation of my compiler.

If you believe I am confused, that's because I am a bit.

Comment: You are overthinking it. The library will be compiled to use the endiness of your C compiler.   NSUTF32StringEncoding should be fine for most anything.   The game changes if you are exporting to non-iOS hosts.

Comment: In that case you would want to add a option to export files.  Your export file format should be big-endian to be compatible with Network Byte Order.

Comment: @starbolin: `NSUTF32StringEncoding` is problematic, it will especially cause problems in the `NSString` -> `wchar_t` direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why `wchar_t` is impossible to recommend, except when you need to work directly with the Windows API.

On iOS, `wchar_t` is UTF-32 with the native byte order.  This is *technically* not the same thing as `NSUTF32StringEncoding`, which indicates either byte order with a BOM.

Here's some copy pasta from the last time I answered this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610871/how-to-copy-a-wchar-t-into-an-nsstring/2610989#2610989)):

```
#include <machine/endian.h>
#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN
#define WCHAR_ENCODING NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding
#elif BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN
#define WCHAR_ENCODING NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding
#endif
```

**The problem with** using `NSUTF32StringEncoding` is that it will only work for converting `wchar_t` to `NSString`, but not necessarily the other way around.  It will stick a BOM on the front (undesirable) and it may even give you data in the wrong endian.

It is also possible that using `NSUTF32StringEncoding` will cause errors even going from `wchar_t` to `NSString`, but that is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp Why is the BOM undesirable? Without it you'd run into issues like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458708/converting-an-nsstring-to-and-from-utf32

Comment: @LuisCien: BOM is only appropriate at the beginning of a document. If you use NSUTF32StringEncoding to convert to wchar_t and then do normal string operations (e.g. wprintf), you will get several U+FEFF characters spread throughout your documents. Remember that U+FEFF is only BOM at the beginning of a document, if you have it somewhere else it is a zero-width no break space. You also don't want weird things like `wcslen(L"A") = 2`. In short, BOM is undesirable in strings in the general case.

Comment: @LuisCien: Or in other words, `wchar_t` is *not* UTF-32 on iOS, and if you add a BOM then you are encoding the string *incorrectly.* The correct encoding for `wchar_t` on iOS is UTF-32LE.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: ah, makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, it is not safe to assume a wchar_t* string is UTF-32 encoded.

If you are very concerned about this and want it to be robust as possible, convert the wchar_t* string in to UTF-8 encoded char* string using wcstombs_l(). Specify the "UTF-8" locale with newlocale(). This will reliably convert a wchar_t* string into a UTF-8 encoded char* string. You can convert back with mbstowcs_l().

Once you have a UTF-8 encoded char* you should be all set for NSString conversions with NSUTF8StringEncoding. Yes, it's an extra hoop. Just jump through it.

Comment: It is not safe in general.  However, it is safe on iOS.

Comment: Besides why is it not safe to assume a wchar_t* string is UTF-32 encoded, given it is 32 bits? Is this because of the subtil difference between UCS-4 and UTF-32? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Additionally, if it's not safe to "assume", how will `wcstombs_l` do it without "assuming"? Will it inspect the text looking for a BOM or something?

Comment: @DietrichEpp As pointed out earlier wchar_t* is not expected to have a BOM, which may or may not be in a UTF-32 string. Additionally, UTF-32 still has escaping and meta characters; which are not expected in wchar_t* strings. Not to mention other Unicode oddities like combining characters and code points with multiple positions.

Comment: wcstombs_l() is designed to convert wchar_t* to a multi-byte character sequence for a specified locale. That's its job. How it does it is implementation details. Let it do all the heavy lifting of resolving encoding issues.

Comment: I still don't get your point: combining characters are totally a non issue for converting from UTF-32 to UTF-8. What do you mean by "escaping and meta characters"? Can you give a reference to what wchar_t* strings are supposed to contain or not contain? I still can't see why it wouldn't be safe to assume a 32-bit wchar_t* strings is UTF-32.

Comment: `wcstombs_l` implementation is more than an implementation detail. In order to decide whether it does what I want, I need to understand what it does. and I'm sorry but "Convert wide-character string to multibyte string" is ambiguous. I need a better specification. Beyond that, I still want to understand at least a naive way to do what it does, exactly the same way that when I use, say, `memcpy`, I know what it does or does not, even if the two memory areas overlap.

Comment: finally, `wcstombs_l` is not referenced at http://www.cplusplus.com/ which mentions only `wcstombs`. Neither does it mention `newlocale`. You mention UTF-8 being a locale, which is totally at odd with my understanding of what UTF-8 and locales are. In short, what you say totally puzzles me. Sokal?

Comment: The Apple doc for [mcstombs_l(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/wcstombs_l.3.html) and [newlocale(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/xlocale.3.html)

Comment: _combining characters are totally a non issue for converting from UTF-32 to UTF-8_ -- You are not converting between UTF-32 and UTF-8, you are converting between wchar_t* and UTF-8. The whole point of this is wchar_t* is not UTF-32.

Comment: My last statement on the topic. Take it however you want. wchar_t* is NOT Unicode. [UTF-32](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf32-1), UTF-16, and UTF-8 are all encodings for Unicode. The key here is they are ENCODINGS, not 1-to-1 mappings of Unicode endpoints. Assuming that UTF-32 == Unicode == wchar_t* will result in buggy and insecure code. The safe way to go from wchar_t* to NSString is wchar_t* to UTF-8, then UTF-8 to NSString. This is because there are system provided ways of doing this conversion, and it not just blindly casting **mostly** compatible datatypes.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. If you find time for another one, I'd really like to know why "Assuming that UTF-32 == Unicode == wchar_t* will result in buggy and insecure code". For me wchar_t* **is** UTF-32, I really can't see any alternative.